Unexpected Response from Photodiode Being Used to Measure Laser Irradiance
Like the title suggests, I am trying to measure the irradiance of a laser. This is done using an integrating sphere and a photodiode. The light that enters the integrating sphere has to travel through a plasma. This plasma is created via a burst of light, the burst consists of fifty pulses which present as a fifty impulse responses when viewed using an oscilloscope (something like | | | | | where each '|' is a pulse). All together, there are two photodiodes, one that captures the burst before the plasma that is used as a reference (photodiode A), and one photodiode that is used to measure the irradiance after travelling through the plasma (photodiode B).
Note I have no idea how the circuit for photodiode A is done because I cannot take it apart without messing up the setup entirely.
The circuit I am using for photodiode B is very simple, a 12VDC battery connected to a capacitor which is in parallel with a resistor. The capacitor goes straight back to ground and the resistor is in series with the photodiode which is in series with a cable that I used to connect to the oscilloscope.
The interesting part is that when I view the burst through photodiode B, the shape on the oscilloscope is sinusoidal with peaks corresponding to the peaks from the reference. This doesn't make any sense to me because from previous trials the result from photodiode B looked almost exactly like the result from photodiode A, just a bit smaller in amplitude. This started happening after I had to repair the circuit because someone accidentally broke it.
Any help or suggestions as to the root cause of the issue would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Wavelength 1030nm, iirc resistance 100 Ohm, capacitance I don't know, pulse duration roughly 350fs repetition frequency maybe 5nm but I'm not sure, no idea what the photodiode model is. I was not the one who built it originally.
Circuit, the little line pointed down is where I connected the oscilloscope:

Example from oscilloscope, yellow is reference, blue is photodiode B:


We would need at least the schematic of your setup with component values, your photodiode's datasheet, the wavelength, pulse repetition frequency and duration, and oscillograms to begin to give you a definitive answer on this one.

I added that as an edit, hopefully it is more clear now.

Irradiance is flux density [mW/mm^2] which for a narrow beam why use a sphere to measure density?

The blue signal is being high pass filtered, meaning no DC current path is present. Assuming you built the circuit exactly as drawn, my guess is a bad solder joint.

Does your DSO have enough BW to capture accurate peaks? an integrator might be needed.

The circuitry for diode A, the (battery-powered) circuitry for diode B, and the oscilloscope must all share a  common ground, which is not shown in your schematic, making it impossible to know what signal to expect from B. Show this ground and oscilloscope probe point, please.

About the fact the blue signal is being high pass filtered do you think it could be caused by the capacitor if it were soldered poorly?

Resolved the issue. For anyone that thought the this problem was interesting, the solution will likely disappoint you. Turns out there was a bit on excess solder on the anode of the photodiode that ended up dripping onto the casing that caused a short, casing of photodiode is connected to the casing of the oscilloscope cable. Didn't think to do a continuity test between the anode and casing! Removed the excess solder and everything is working smoothly now.

The traces seems to indicate that the blue oscilloscope input may be set to "AC coupled", and the yellow is set to "DC coupled". First make sure they both have the same settings, if you expect to see similar traces.
Your own schematic shows only one connection to the oscilloscope, which makes no sense. You must connect oscilloscope ground to one node, while you probe another, requiring two connections. Being battery powered, this module is electrically isolated from everything else, and you may connect the oscilloscope between any two nodes you choose.
The most logical choice of nodes is shown below. Make sure that you are measuring diode current, with the correct polarity. This would be proportional to the voltage across R1, with node A having the higher (most positive) potential:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
By measuring the voltage across R1, you ensure that any DC offset in the signal is due to dark current only. Photo-current due to illumination of the photo-diode causes A to rise in potential with respect to ground B, appearing as a fluctuation on top of any offset due to dark current.

I'll start with checking the "AC Coupled" setting you mentioned, but I think the oscilloscope is connected to a common ground, when I soldered the connector for the oscilloscope there was a second prong that I connected to ground the metal casing on the connector that I soldered to a third prong on the photodiode. I think I heard in passing it was called "shielding" but I wasn't sure so I didn't add it to the schematic. If those don't work I'll re-solder the connector to where you suggest.
